# Can I reboot phone without root access on b4a?

Tags: android, basic4android

How to reboot phone without root access on b4a?
Only need root access with ML library?

Code:

```
Sub Globals
         Dim M as MLfiles
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
       M.GetRoot
       M.RootCmd("reboot","",Null,Null,False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that we have to use this permission in our project for use reboot

Comment: @hanLay It will not work without Root, But to gain permission you can add this code to the manifest editor.

AddManifestText(
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"
  android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
)